# web rtc working fine in interanet(local home connection) but not on internet(world internet)

Tags: webrtc

When I use it with my local connection the connection works perfectly fine (for example me and my mom who connected to same wifi as me) but not my friend that lives in another city

take a look at the frontend code

```js
  let sendChannel;
  let receiveChannel;
  let localConnection;
  let remoteConnection;
  let is_girl = false;
  let is_boy = false;
  let girlCodeExecuted = false;
  let boyCodeExecuted = false;
  let connected = false;
  let hasReceivedAnswer = false;
  let hasReceivedoffer = false;
  let intervalID;
  let offer;
  let answer;

  const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
    },
    {
      urls: "TURNS:freeturn.net:5349",
      username: 'free',
      credential: 'free' 
    },
  ],
};


  function skip() {
      if (is_boy) {
          localConnection.close();

      } else if (is_girl) {
          remoteConnection.close();

      }
      
  }
  
  function onConnect() {
      var skipButton = document.getElementById('skip');
      skipButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
      connected = true;
      clearInterval(intervalID)
      ulll.innerHTML = '';
  }
  
  function onDisconnect() {
      sendChannel = undefined;
      receiveChannel = undefined;
      localConnection = undefined;
      remoteConnection = undefined;
      offer = undefined;
      answer = undefined;
      is_girl = false;
      is_boy = false;
      girlCodeExecuted = false;
      boyCodeExecuted = false;
      hasReceivedAnswer = false;
      hasReceivedoffer = false;
      connected = false;
      console.log('ondisconnect');
      var skipButton = document.getElementById('skip');
      skipButton.setAttribute('disabled', '');
      intervalID = setInterval(sendhello, 1000);   
      reconnect();
    
  }
  
  var socket = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.host + '/text/');
  var ulll = document.querySelector("#ulll");
  
  function reconnect() {
        console.log("Reconnecting...");
      socket = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.host + '/text/');
      socket.onmessage = async function (event) {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log(data);
      if (data.waiting_users) {
          if (data.waiting_users[0] === '{{user.username}}') {
              await boy();
              is_boy = true;
              console.log('hi boy');
          }
  
          if (data.waiting_users[1] === '{{user.username}}') {
              is_girl = true;
              console.log('hi girl');
          }
      }
      offer = await data.offer;
  
      if (offer && is_girl && !hasReceivedoffer) {
          console.log('entered stage2');
          await girl(offer);
          hasReceivedoffer = true
      }

      answer = await data.answer;

      if(answer){clearInterval(intervalID)}
      
      if (answer&& is_boy && !hasReceivedAnswer) {
        await localConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
        console.log('boy just received answer');
        hasReceivedAnswer = true;
    
      }
  };
  }
  
async function boy() {
    if (!boyCodeExecuted) {
        console.log('boy is running');
    localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    localConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
        console.log("ICE candidate event:", e);
        if (localConnection.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
            console.log("NEW ice candidate!!");
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({ offer: localConnection.localDescription }));
        }
    };

    sendChannel = localConnection.createDataChannel("sendChannel");
    sendChannel.onmessage = e => {
        console.log("Received message on sendChannel:", e.data);
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = 'you';
        li.textContent = e.data;
        li.classList.add("new-message");
        ulll.appendChild(li);
    }

    sendChannel.onopen = e => {
        console.log("sendChannel opened");
        sendChannel.send('به {{ user.name }} {{user.age}} ساله از {{ user.city }} متصل شدید باهم دوست باشید :)');
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({ d: 'hola' }));
        socket.close();
        console.log('boy is connected');
        onConnect();
    }

    sendChannel.onclose = e => {
        console.log("sendChannel closed");
        ulll.innerHTML = '<li>درحال پیدا کردن کاربر ...</li>';
        console.log("closed!");
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').srcObject = undefined;
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').src = "{% static 'loading.mp4' %}";
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').loop = true;
        console.log('boy is disconnected');
        onDisconnect();
    }

    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
    console.log("Local stream:", stream);
    document.getElementById('localVideo').srcObject = stream;

    localStream = stream;
    document.getElementById('localVideo').muted = true;
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        console.log("Adding track to localConnection:", track);
        localConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });

    offer = await localConnection.createOffer();
    console.log("Created offer:", offer);
    await localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    localConnection.ontrack = event => {
        console.log('ontrack event fired in boy function');
        if (event.streams[0]) {
            console.log('Stream is defined in ontrack event');
            document.getElementById('remoteVideo').srcObject = event.streams[0];
            document.getElementById('remoteVideo').loop = false;
        } else {
            console.log('Stream is not defined in ontrack event');
            document.getElementById('remoteVideo').src = "{% static 'loading.mp4' %}";
            document.getElementById('remoteVideo').loop = true;
        }
    };

    localConnection.onclose = event => {
        console.log('Connection closed in boy function');
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').src = "{% static 'loading.mp4' %}";
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').loop = true;
    };
    boyCodeExecuted = true
    }
}

async function girl(offer) {
    if (!girlCodeExecuted) {
        console.log('girl is running');
    remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

    remoteConnection.ondatachannel = e => {
            console.log("Data channel event:", e);
            receiveChannel = e.channel;
            receiveChannel.onmessage = e => {
                console.log("Received message on receiveChannel:", e.data);
                let li = document.createElement('li');
                li.id = 'you';
                li.textContent = e.data;
                li.classList.add("new-message");
                ulll.appendChild(li);
            };
            receiveChannel.onopen = e => {
                console.log("receiveChannel opened");
                receiveChannel.send('به {{ user.name }} {{user.age}} ساله از {{ user.city }} متصل شدید باهم دوست باشید :)');
                socket.close();
                console.log('girl is connected');
                onConnect();
            };

            receiveChannel.onclose = e => {
                console.log("receiveChannel closed");
                ulll.innerHTML = '<li>درحال پیدا کردن کاربر ...</li>';
                console.log("closed!!!!!!");
                document.getElementById('remoteVideo').srcObject = undefined;
                document.getElementById('remoteVideo').src = "{% static 'loading.mp4' %}";
                document.getElementById('remoteVideo').loop = true;
                console.log('girl is disconnected');
                onDisconnect();
            };
            remoteConnection.channel = receiveChannel;
        };
 
        if (remoteConnection.signalingState !== 'have-remote-offer') {
        remoteConnection.ontrack = event => {
        console.log("ontrack event fired in girl function");
        if (event.streams && event.streams[0]) {
            console.log('Stream is defined in ontrack event');
            document.getElementById('remoteVideo').srcObject = event.streams[0];
            document.getElementById('remoteVideo').loop = false;
        }
    };

    await remoteConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
    console.log("Local stream:", stream);
    document.getElementById('localVideo').srcObject = stream;
    document.getElementById('localVideo').muted = true;
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        console.log("Adding track to remoteConnection:", track);
        remoteConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
    });

    let answer = await remoteConnection.createAnswer();
    console.log("Created answer:", answer);
    await remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

    remoteConnection.onclose = event => {
        console.log('Connection closed in girl function');
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').src = "{% static 'loading.mp4' %}";
        document.getElementById('remoteVideo').loop = true;
    };

    console.log("Sending answer:", remoteConnection.localDescription);
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({ answer: remoteConnection.localDescription }));
}
    girlCodeExecuted = true;
    }
}

function girl_message(message) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.id = "me";
      li.textContent = message;
  
      let ul = document.querySelector("#ulll");
      ul.appendChild(li);
  
      li.classList.add("new-message");
  
      remoteConnection.channel.send(message);
      document.getElementById('text').value = '';
  }
  
  function boy_message(message) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.id = "me";
      li.textContent = message;
  
      let ul = document.querySelector("#ulll");
      ul.appendChild(li);
  
      li.classList.add("new-message");
  
      sendChannel.send(message);
      document.getElementById('text').value = '';
  }
  
  socket.onopen = () => { console.log('یه سوکت باز شد'); }

  function sendhello() {
  if(!connected){
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({helele : 'jehehe'}))
    console.log('sending shit');}
}

  intervalID = setInterval(sendhello, 1000);

  socket.onmessage = async function (event) {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log(data);
      if (data.waiting_users) {
          if (data.waiting_users[0] === '{{user.username}}') {
              await boy();
              is_boy = true;
              console.log('hi boy');
          }
  
          if (data.waiting_users[1] === '{{user.username}}') {
              is_girl = true;
              console.log('hi girl');
          }
      }
      offer = await data.offer;
  
      if (offer && is_girl && !hasReceivedoffer) {
          console.log('entered stage2');
          await girl(offer);
          hasReceivedoffer = true
      }

      answer = await data.answer;

      if(answer){clearInterval(intervalID)}
      
      if (answer&& is_boy && !hasReceivedAnswer) {
        await localConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
        console.log('boy just received answer');
        hasReceivedAnswer = true;
    
      }
  };

  socket.onclose = (event) => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection closed with code ' + event.code);
      clearInterval(intervalID)
  };
  
  function send_message() {
      let message = document.getElementById('text').value
      console.log(message)
      if (is_boy) {
          boy_message(message);
      } else if (is_girl) {
          girl_message(message);
          message = '';
      }
  }
  
  const textInput = document.getElementById('text');
  textInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
          send_message()
      }
  });
```

in the backend I use Django channels which is not the problem and in console of both I see that they take the offer and answer
please help me my whole life is on this project.

I tried many free turn servers like metered and express turn but the problem stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your ice servers definition isn't correct. Just use:

```
iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"],
    },
    {
      urls: ["turn:freeturn.net:5349"],
      username: "free",
      credential: "free" 
    },
],
```

Comment: well didnt changed anything